# Работа с pdf в Android

Tags: pdf, android, java

Стоит задача реализации функционала для работы с PDF-журналами. Нужно организовать разбор, просмотр по страницам ну и т.д. Погуглив - много чего нашел(например EbookDroid), но все это кажется уж больно геморрным. Нужно компилить нативный код, править его, снова компилить, разбираться в тонах кода.

Кто работал с pdf в Андроид подскажите хорошие либы, тулзы, хорошие способы работы с данным форматом. Вообщем, интересно как можно упростить задачу и что для этого юзать.

В ios в этом плане гораздо проще.

И да, [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665957/pdf-parsing-library-for-android) я естественно находил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть разной сырости проекты по чтению PDF в Андроиде:

1. [AndPDF](http://andpdf.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/andpdf/trunk/AndroidPdfViewer/src/com/sun/pdfview/)
2. [Android PDF](http://code.google.com/p/android-pdf/)
3. [PDF Edit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfedit/)

Сам с PDF в Android'е не работал, только показывал - и это совсем несложно в отличие от парсинга PDF'а

Comment: Все кроме последнего есть по ссылке в моем вопросе. Ммм, это мне не особо поможет.